# Wrapping ulong variables with arithmatic operators

Tags: c#, overflow, word-wrap, ulong

I'm somewhat confused regarding the nature of intentionally overflowing structures like ulong in C#.

Essentially I'm working on a grid that I want to be ulong.max X ulong.max squares.  If I perform an arithmetic operation on the coordinates I want it to automatically wrap over the other side of the grid.  However, it seems if I multiply two ulongs together and it results in an overflow, I end up with zero instead of the "modulus(ulong.max)" of whatever I would have otherwise.  Maybe I misunderstand what is supposed to happen when I overflow a 64 bit ulong.

Any help on ways to make a wrapping coordinate system for a grid that allow the numbers to automatically wrap around would be great.  Maybe this isn't possible?

I'm feeding in "longs" and converting them to "ulongs" bitwise which ends up with coordinates like:

(-1,0) = (0xFFFFFFFF, 0x00000000)

(-2,0) = (0xFFFFFFFE, 0x00000000)

Anyway, any pointers on ways to make a fully wrapping coordinate grid would be helpful.  Maybe my brain simply isn't working today and I'm missing something obvious that's causing it to go haywire at high ulong numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, it seems if I multiply two ulongs together and it results in an overflow, I end up with zero instead of the "modulus(ulong.max)" of whatever I would have otherwise.

You wouldn't get the result `modulus(ulong.max)` - you would get the result `modulus(ulong.max + 1)`.

For example:

```
ulong x = 10000000000L;
ulong y = 2000000000L;
Console.WriteLine(x * y); // 1553255926290448384
```

Basically, wrap-around works exactly as you should expect it to.

I would recommend using `byte` for simpler examples though. For example:

```
byte x = 150;
byte y = 2;
byte z = (byte) (x * y); // 44 (300 % 256)
```

It's easier to think of 255 + 1 wrapping to 0 than it is to have to think about 18446744073709551615. But fundamentally they will behave the same way (after a cast - otherwise "`byte` arithmetic" is actually performed after promotion to `int` - that doesn't happen with `ulong`, of course.)

Comment: For some reason my perlin generator is just smearing any coordinate "below 0" after the long has been converted (bitwise) to ulong...

Comment: @ThisHandleNotInUse: I don't know anything out "perlin generators" but if you've got code that doesn't behave as you expect it to, it would be handy to see that as a short but complete program.

Comment: It's like 300 lines so I didn't post it as it's a perlin generator modified for specific use.  I have no idea where to localize for my error - the last generator I made I wrapped it over a much smaller interval which made it no big deal as the numbers were never trying to multiply themselves into an "overflow" / wrap-around...

Comment: @ThisHandleNotInUse: Well presumably there's *some* operation that you expect to have one result, but actually it has a different result. You should probably be able to spot that with debugging or logging. We can't really help you further without seeing some code.

Comment: I understand - I was just hoping someone might know something I don't about how the underlying arithmetic works that results in, say, multiplying 0xFFFFFFFF * 0xFFFFFFFF and having it just wrap around to the appropriate remainder that still fits in the register.

Comment: @ThisHandleNotInUse: But that's exactly what *does* happen, as per the examples in my answer. Your expectation is correct, barring the off-by-one error in the question. You still haven't shown any examples where that's not the case.

Comment: I've figured out the problem.  I was using ((ulong % float) / float) which results in 0 always on very large numbers but results in the expected number for lower numbers... Sorry to waste time.  It has to be ulong%ulong for big ulongs... I have no idea the mechanics behind that.

Comment: @ThisHandleNotInUse: Right. I try to avoid using `%` with floating point numbers, as it makes my head hurt :)